# Почему для hibernate свойства можно прописать только через hibernate.properties

Tags: hibernate, format, properties

Почему у меня через файл hibernate.properties получается задать свойства:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А через application.properties не получается?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Моя задача: отформатировать SQL запрос, чтобы в консоли он выводился красиво.
У меня это НЕ получается сделать через файл application.properties. Почему? В этом весь вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело было в том, что у меня приложение не было spring-boot приложением. Поэтому файл application.properties не считывался.